# how to handle sequelize transaction properly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, sequelize.js

I wrote the code to commit and rollback using a sequelize transaction. But I do not know whether I need to declare it every time, by calling `sequelize.transaction()` at the top of every part, where transaction should be applied.

I want to find a more structured and reusable method. For example, should I use middleware or some design pattern? Please let me know.

--- update ---
Sorry, previous question is wrong.

In sequelize, the question was what to do when resource access is restricted by transaction isolation level.

At a high level of isolation, if a resource is accessed at the same time, it throws an error. Is there a way to try this again or do something right?

In some cases even locks at the table level
It directly accesses the database and releases the lock.

Comment: There are feature for Automatically pass transactions to all queries and auto commit. This maybe help bit. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html#automatically-pass-transactions-to-all-queries

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By the way, if the query is executed using sequelize, is it automatically rolled back if an error occurs? I thought it could cause a memory leak because the transaction did not shut down gracefully.

Comment: It will rollback properly If one or several of the promises are rejected.

Comment: Thank you very much. But is promise reject valid even if it is not the value returned by sequelize?

Comment: Of course. Make sure all of your stuff in the transaction promise. https://pastebin.com/qemZXYuZ

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [`zb-sequelize`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zb-sequelize) npm package.
It simplifies transaction management extremely by adding 2 decorators.

```
import { Transactional, Tx } from 'zb-sequelize';

@Transactional
function fooBar(@Tx transaction) {
  foo(transaction);
  bar(transaction);
}

@Transactional
function foo(@Tx transaction) {
}

@Transactional
function bar(@Tx transaction) {
}
```